# Insert image with line-broken texts inside a table cell

Tags: tables, graphics, line-breaking

I am able to insert an image in a table but I am having difficulties with the format adding text below the image. I don't want to use caption because I don't want to have "Figure x" showing up. Ideally it should be something like this:

[image]

I have tried

`\includegraphics[scale=1]{img/Picture1}\newline Dummy Text`

but it didn't work.

Any input is appreciated!

Here's the requested executable format of my latex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{| l{} |l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
  & \includegraphics[scale=1]{img/Picture1}\newline
  Some Dummy Data
  & \includegraphics[scale=1]{img/Picture2}\newline
  Some Dummy Data
  & \includegraphics[scale=1]{img/Picture3}\newline
Some Dummy Data
  & \includegraphics[scale=1]{img/Picture4}\newline
Some Dummy Data
  & \includegraphics[scale=1]{img/Picture5}\newline
Some Dummy Data 
  & \includegraphics[scale=1]{img/Picture6}\newline
Some Dummy Data 
  & \includegraphics[scale=1]{img/Picture7}  \\ \hline
  &   &   &   &   &  &  &  \\ \hline
  &   &   &   &   &  &  &  \\ \hline
  &   &   &   &   &  &  &  \\ \hline
  &   &   &   &   &  &  &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Can you provide the `MWE` as in executable format, i.e., from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: @MadyYuvi sure, I have added them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage{subfigure} % this package is obsolete, use subfig or subcaption instead

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht] % just h! can cause problems ...
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth} % common settings of caption width
    \setcellgapes{3pt} % additinal vertical space around cells content
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| l | * {6}{X|}}  % that table is fit between text borders
                                               % and text in cells can be automatic broken
    \hline
    &   \includegraphics{example-image-duck}\par
        Some Dummy Data
    &   \includegraphics{example-image-duck}\par
        Some Dummy Data
    &   \includegraphics{example-image-duck}\par
        Some Dummy Data
    &   \includegraphics{example-image-duck}\par
        Some Dummy Data
    &   \includegraphics{example-image-duck}\par
        Some Dummy Data
    &   \includegraphics{example-image-duck}\par
        Some Dummy Data         \\
    \hline
1   & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7     \\ \hline
    &   &   &   &   &   &       \\ \hline
    &   &   &   &   &   &       \\ \hline
    &   &   &   &   &   &       \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```